# Is there a way to still debug iPhone 5s with Xcode 4

Tags: ios, xcode, arm, 64-bit

If i try to debug an iPhone 5s on Xcode 4 it will say:

Xcode does not know how to run code on "arm64" devices.  However if I compile an adhoc ipa, it will install and run.

We still need Xcode 4 for temporary reasons.

Any ideas?

Comment: no                no  no no no no no

Comment: We have business reasons, I'm not sure why you are recommending me to go solve my 'business reasons" instead of suggesting something that is actually useful.  I'm just dev, and I'm not in a position to tell biz dev to go f themselvs.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to use Organizer to copy your target app ( after you built it ) directly into your iPhone 5s.. Of course you can't debug it but at least you can run it on the device.